# Cypher: Issue with replacement for ! property operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just saw (here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9/deprecations.html) that the ! operator for Cypher property expressions will be deprecated with the release of Neo4j 2.0. So I went to reformulate my existing Cypher queries and ran into the following problem.

1.9 query:
`START n=node(*) WHERE NOT "NO_FACET" in n.uniqueLabels! RETURN n limit 2;`

What I get: Nodes which either don't have the "uniqueLabels" property at all OR nodes that have this property but do not contain the "NO_FACET" value.

The page linked above says to circumvent such expressions by doing a check like `has(n.uniqueLabels" AND NOT "NO_FACET" IN n.uniqueLabels`. This query works, but it is obviously not what I wanted (I also wanted nodes back that don't have the property at all).
The proposed circumvention looks like a lazy AND-evaluation which would be fine to me. So I did this:

`START n=node(*) WHERE NOT (has(n.uniqueLabels) AND "NO_FACET" in n.uniqueLabels) RETURN n limit 2;`

But here I get an error:
`==> EntityNotFoundException: The property 'uniqueLabels' does not exist on Node[0]`
So the evaluation is not so lazy after all? The weird thing, this query works:

`START n=node(*) WHERE has(n.uniqueLabels) AND "NO_FACET" in n.uniqueLabels RETURN n limit 2;`

It just gives me the exact opposite of what I wanted, of course.

Actually I can get what I want without the operator like this:

`START n=node(*) WHERE NOT has(n.uniqueLabels) OR (has(n.uniqueLabels) AND NOT "NO_FACET" in n.uniqueLabels) RETURN n limit 2;`

But I'm not sure if this is how it was intended when the operator was deprecated. So the question is whether I miss the right way to do it or if the behavior of AND in conjunction with a NOT outside the parentheses is a bug perhaps?

And by the way: Does anyone now why the ! operator has been deprecated in the first place? I like it ;-)

Thank you for reading and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be caused by how the NOT is evaluating the expression within it. It may not be short circuiting the AND expression, which would cause it to not evaluation the second expression.

One solution is [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)(Busting out the CS 101). You query would turn into this:

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE NOT(has(n.uniqueLabels)) OR NOT("NO_FACET" in n.uniqueLabels)) 
RETURN n limit 2;
```

I'm not 100% sure why the deprecated this operator, it may have to do with making the Cypher language keywords more in line with something like SQL, but you situation seems more like a bug in their system, as the expression should short circuit on the AND within the NOT statement.

Comment: Your're right, I could of course just reformulate the query. But since the deprecation page gives instruction on how to replace the operator, I was wondering why it seemingly wouldn't work as things get a little more complex. This leaves me with two options: Don't change anything now and wait until this issue is resolved, or reformulate all my queries with the risk of doing unnecessary work. For the moment, I will opt for waiting since everything is working at the moment.

Comment: It may have been one of those situations that they had not considered when setting the page up.